# Processing a large (GB) file, quickly and multiple times (Java)

Tags: java, machine-learning, bigdata, large-files

What options are there for processing large files quickly, multiple times?

I have a single file (min 1.5 GB, but can be upwards of 10-15 GB) that needs to be read multiple times - on the order of hundreds to thousands of times. The server has a large amount of RAM (64+ GB) and plenty of processors (24+).

The file will be sequential, read-only. Files are encrypted (sensitive data) on disk. I also use MessagePack to deserialize them into objects during the read process.

I cannot store the objects created from the file into memory - too large of an expansion (1.5 GB file turns into 35 GB in-memory object array). File can't be stored as a byte array (limited by Java's array length of 2^32-1).

My initial thought is to use a memory mapped file, but that has its own set of limitations.

The idea is to get the file off the disk and into memory for processing.

The large volume of data is for a machine learning algorithm, that requires multiple reads. During the calculation of each file pass, there's a considerable amount of heap usage by the algorithm itself, which is unavoidable, hence the requirement to read it multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have here is that you cannot `mmap()` the way the system call of the same name does; the syscall can map up to 2^64, `FileChannel#map()` cannot map more than 2^30 reliably.

However, what you can do is wrap a `FileChannel` into a class and create several "map ranges" covering all the file.

I have done "nearly" such a thing except more complicated: [largetext](https://github.com/fge/largetext). More complicated because I have to do the decoding process to boot, and the text which is loaded must be so into memory, unlike you who reads bytes. Less complicated because I have a define JDK interface to implement and you don't.

You can however use nearly the same technique using Guava and a `RangeMap<Long, MappedByteBuffer>`.

I implement `CharSequence` in this project above; I suggest that you implement a `LargeByteMapping` interface instead, from which you can read whatever parts you want; or, well, whatever suits you. Your main problem will be to *define that interface*. I suspect what `CharSequence` does is not what you want.

Meh, I may even have a go at it some day, `largetext` is quite exciting a project and this looks like the same kind of thing; except less complicated, ultimately!

One could even imagine a `LargeByteMapping` implementation where a factory would create such mappings with only a small part of that into memory and the rest written to a file; and such an implementation would also use the principle of locality: the latest queried part of the file into memory would be kept into memory for faster access.

See also [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48411/can-i-make-the-thread-safe-case-faster).

---

**EDIT** I feel some more explanation is needed here... A `MappedByteBuffer` will NOT EAT HEAP SPACE!!

It will eat *address space only*; it is nearly the equivalent of a `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`, except it is backed by a file.

And a very important distinction needs to be made here; all of the text above supposes that you are reading *bytes, not characters*!

Comment: Regarding the LargeByteMapping factory, the entire file needs to be in memory at one time, because there's a minimum of 24 threads reading from it at a time. Currently, it's using a ByteSource to open a new buffered stream to the file for each thread. 

I'll take a look through the largetext project.

Comment: Eh no... It has to be in memory only if you need it to be. A `MappedByteBuffer` WILL NOT eat heap space!

Comment: Look at the edit here. One thing you don't tell and which is quite important here is whether you need to read bytes or text. The problem space is quite different! In the second case it is MUCH more complicated.

Comment: I've edited it. They're read in bytes. Here's the edit:
Files are encrypted (sensitive data) on disk. I also use MessagePack to deserialize them into objects during the read process.

Comment: It can be decrypted in memory, but must remain encrypted on disk.

Comment: OK, does your encryption/decryption algorithm use fixed size blocks? That is, if I read from offset x and y, can I decrypt this range individually as long as x and y are on block boundaries?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51916/discussion-between-fge-and-marcus)

Answer (score 0):

Figure out how to structure the data. Get a good book about NoSQL and find the appropriate Database (Wide-Column, Graph, etc.) for your scenario. That's what I'd do. You'd not only have sophisticated query methods on your data but also mangling the data using distribute map-reduced implementations doing whatever you want. Maybe that's what you want (you even dropped the *bigdata* bomb)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating "a dictionary" as the bridge between your program and the target file? Your program will call the dictionary then dictionary will refer you to the big fat file.